# VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, INDEX / MATCH or OFFSET?

Tags: excel, autocomplete, vlookup

I have two sheets, with one table each:

**Sheet_1**:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | Name | Address  |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | Mark | Street A |
|  2 | John | Street B |
+----+------+----------+
```

**Sheet_2**:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | Name |  Adress  |
+----+------+----------+
|  0 | aaaa | bbbbbbbb |
|  0 | aaaa | bbbbbbbb |
+----+------+----------+
```

Sheet_1 is for reference and Sheet_2 is for input.

When I input the **ID 1 (A2)** in **Sheet 2** (`=Sheet_1!B2`) I need the other columns to fill themselves accordingly. In this case it would be: **B2: Mark** and **C2: Street A**, and so on.

What's the best method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Vlookup formula. In Sheet2 Cell B2 use the following:

```
=vlookup(A2, Sheet1!A:C, 2, false)
```

This will lookup value A2 (which you just inputted) in the first column of the range Sheet1!A:C. It will then return the value found in the second columns of the same range (column B) which will be the Name.

For cell C2 you can use the same formula, just change out the 2 for the 3 to reference the third column of the range:

```
=vlookup(A2, Sheet1!A:C, 3, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the ID in ColumnA (say in Row4):

```
=VLOOKUP($A4,Sheet_1!$A:$C,COLUMN(),0)
```

in Sheet_2 B4 copied across one column and both down to suit may serve.